# Footer is not showing in Porto Theme Magento 1.9.1

Tags: php, magento-1.9, magento2

I have Installed Porto Theme in magento.The Footer is not showing on the Homepage only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you purchased Porto Magento Theme! please be sure to always check out this documentation. Porto Magento Theme outline all kinds of good information, and provide you with all the details you need to use Porto Magento Theme. Porto can only be used with Magento 1.x or 2.x

If you are unable to find your answer here in our documentation, contact to support team through themeforest item support page with your site CPanel(or FTP) and magento admin details.

Please find below documentation of Porto Magento Theme and Support Team URLs.

http://www.newsmartwave.net/magento/porto/documentation/

https://themeforest.net/item/porto-ultimate-responsive-magento-theme/9725864/support

I Hope It's helpful for you.